# Question regarding inverse functions: Let f : X --> Y if E belongs to Y (subset) show that E is a subset of f^1(f(E).

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So here is the problem:

$$ Let\ f : X\rightarrow Y, where \ f \ is \ a \ function. \\ \  \\ Prove  \ that \ for \ all  \ E\subset Y \ , \ it \ follows \ that \ f^{-1}(f(E))\supset E \\ \ \\ Provide \ example \ of \ f,X, Y,E \ such  \ that \ \ f(f^{-1}(E))\ne E $$

This confuses me a little bit. First of all, isn't this true:  $$ f^{-1}(f(E))=E \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Then it can't be true that E is a strict subset of E. Also, for f(E) to exist, it means that E is also a subset of X (So that if belongs to the domain of the function.) This whole problem confuses my understanding of what a inverse function is or perhaps I am mistaking that f^-1 sign for inverse function and it's something else...

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}(E)$ in this context probably means *preimage* or *inverse image* of $E\subset Y$. This is the set of all $x\in X$ that map to a member of $E$: formally, $f^{-1}(E)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in E\}$. This definition makes sense regardless of whether the function $f$ is invertible/bijection.

Now, if function $f$ *happens* to have an inverse function, then the image of $E$ in that inverse function (which we also denote $f^{-1}(E)$) can be proven to be equal to the preimage $f^{-1}(E)$ (as defined before), so the notation does not introduce additional confusion.

For examples:

[1] Take $f$ that is not injective: $X=\{1, 2\}, Y=\{0\}, f(1)=f(2)=0$ and $E=\{1\}\subset X$. Then:

$$f(E)=\{f(x):x\in E\}=\{0\}$$ and $$f^{-1}(f(E))=\{x\in X: f(x)\in f(E)\}=\{x\in X:f(x)=0\} = X$$

so $f^{-1}(f(E))$ is a strict superset of $E$.

[2] Take $f$ that is not surjective: $X\{0\}, Y=\{1,2\}, f(0)=1$ and $E=Y=\{1,2\}$. Then:

$$f^{-1}(E)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in E\}=\{0\}$$

and

$$f(f^{-1}(E))=\{f(x):x\in f^{-1}(E)\}=\{f(0)\}=\{1\}$$

so $f(f^{-1}(E))$ is a strict subset of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as others have pointed out, $f^{-1}$ doesn't only stand for inverse function, but also for pre-image; I prefer brackets myself for this notion:

$$f^{-1}[E] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in E\}$$

when $f:X \to Y$ and $E \subseteq Y$.

Secondly, your text denotes by $\subset$ what I would use $\subseteq$ for; there is no suggestion of properly smaller, which would be $\subsetneq$ instead.

So the first statement just says $E \subseteq f^{-1}[f[E]]$, where $E$ has to be a subset of $X$ for $f[E] = \{f(x):x \in E\}$ to make sense.

The fact itself is easily seen : take $x \in E$. Then does $f(x)$ lie in $f[E]$? Yes! by definition it does. So again by definition of pre-image: $x \in f^{-1}[f[E]]$ and the inclusion holds.

It can be a proper one: take $X=Y=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x^2$ and $E=[0,2]$ then $f[E] = [0,4]$ and $f^{-1}[f[E]] = f^{-1}[[0,4]] = [-2,2]$ which is strictly larger than $E$.